# Possible to mine XMR on Nvidia P500 Pascal Mobile?

Tags: gpu-mining, installation

I am getting the following CUDA runtime error

```
nvrtcCompileProgram failed: NVRTC_ERROR_COMPILATION
Program compile log: CryptonightR.cu(297): error: identifier "__activemask" is undefined
          detected during instantiation of "uint32_t shuffle<group_n>(volatile uint32_t *, uint32_t, int, uint32_t) [with group_n=2UL]" 
(429): here

CryptonightR.cu(297): error: identifier "__shfl_sync" is undefined
          detected during instantiation of "uint32_t shuffle<group_n>(volatile uint32_t *, uint32_t, int, uint32_t) [with group_n=2UL]" 
(429): here

CryptonightR.cu(474): error: identifier "__syncwarp" is undefined

CryptonightR.cu(611): error: identifier "__syncwarp" is undefined

4 errors detected in the compilation of "CryptonightR.cu".

[CUDA] Error gpu 0: <cryptonight_gpu_hash>:717 "device kernel image is invalid"
```

when trying

```
minergate-cli --user xxx@gmail.com --xmr 0 -g
```

I have Lenovo P70 with Nvidia Pascal P500. How to resolve the error?

Answer (score 1):

It should be *possible*, but whether your miner supports it is another question.

I'll also point out there has been lots of people very sceptical of minergate. Just search Reddit and draw your own conclusions.

My recommendation is to use either xmrig or xmr-stack and one of the pools the community deem as honest.